# Passing Model and its object as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an MVC 5 application. I have a method as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ModifiedValues<T>(this T obj, T modifiedObject)
{
     foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => !p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
     {
          if (property.GetValue(obj) != null && property.GetValue(modifiedObject) != null)
          {
                if (!(property.GetValue(obj).ToString() == property.GetValue(modifiedObject).ToString()))
                {
                     yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(modifiedObject));
                }
          }

     }
}
```

When I pass it my model name and its object as

```
....ModifiedValues<ABC>(a) // ABC is model and a is an object of ABC
```

It works perfectly fine.

Now I wanted to make a generic method which can accept model and its object as an argument and within that method I require to pass them to the above method. I tried it like this:

```
public void Logto<T>(T modifyObject, IEnumerable<dynamic> query, decimal Id)
{
     var original = db.ABC.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(e => e.N100 == Id);
     var modified = original.ModifiedValues<T>(modifyObject).ToList();
     // some code here
}
```

At

```
.ModifiedValues<T>(modifyObject)
```

the compiler gives an error of **Invalid Arguments**.

Comment: what is the type of ``originalEntity``??

Comment: oh sorry.. type mistake.. its actually original only... `original.ModifiedValues`

Comment: I have edited the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by making a **Public Interface** named IEntity and then as follows:

```
public void Logto<T>(T modifyObject, IEnumerable<dynamic> query, decimal Id) where T : class, IEntity
{
     var original = db.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(e => e.N100 == Id);
     var modified = original.ModifiedValues<T>(modifyObject).ToList();
     // some code here
}
```

And then it works perfectly fine. The problem was that **var original** was getting a query against a specified model i.e. **ABC** but it is calling **ModifiedValues<>** method with a generic type. So, it was invalid argument for the compiler to understand.

When I call the query with a generic model, it works.

Cheers!